# How do you convert a byte array back to jpeg in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, image, byte, jpeg

So in the code below I used fstream to read in a file and convert it to a byte vector, I was wondering if there was a way to convert it back to a jpeg image without downloading an external C++ library.  I feel like there should be a way to just take the bytearray and return the image somehow.

```
std::vector<unsigned int> getByteArray(std::string filename){
    // Define file stream object, and open the file
    std::ifstream file (filename, std::ios::binary); //reads in the file

    // Prepare iterator pairs to iterate the file content!
    std::istream_iterator<unsigned char> begin(file), end; //creates an iterator of type unsigned char to read from begin of ile to end

    std::vector<unsigned int> buffer(begin,end); //putting the values in a vector called buffer

    //std::copy(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), std::ostream_iterator<unsigned int>(std::cout <<","));
    for(int i=0;i<buffer.size();i++){
        std::cout<<buffer[i];
    }



}
```

Comment: How is an array of the bytes making up a JPEG image *not* a JPEG image??

Comment: "return" in what way? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I guess just save as a jpeg file and display the image not the byte array

Comment: Then simply do so! You already managed to read all the bytes. I'm not sure why you think writing them back should be more complicated?

Comment: ***display the image*** That would be dependent on what GUI framework or API you use. Standard `c++` has no concept of a GUI and thus it can't display an image graphically on its own. You may just use functionality to read the image that is builtin to the framework / API.

Comment: Files are bytes. Just a bunch of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You've already got it.

You read all the bytes that constitute your JPEG file.

You've still got them.

You can just write them back to disk now, or do whatever else you want.